# Ввод значений в массив и потоки

Tags: java

Помогите сделать задание с потоками, в котором нужно ввести размер массива, ввести название значений в этом массиве. Я новичок еще.
Вот такой результат должен получится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, который есть уже

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Количество потоков: "); 
     int s = in.nextInt();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Главный поток прерван"); 
        }

        for (int i = s; i >0;i--){ 
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println("Создан поток  " + i + " " + t);
            t.setName(""+i);
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " Завершил свою работу");   
        }    


}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, с чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема при написании кода. Здесь вам могут помочь советом по конкретной проблеме, но не написать/дописать код.

Answer (score 2):

Вот код который Вам нужен

```
public void threadEngine() {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        System.out.print("Size of pool: ");
        int size = new Integer(reader.readLine());
        Thread[] arrayOfThread = new Thread[size];
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            System.out.print("New Thread Name: ");
            arrayOfThread[x] = new Thread(this, reader.readLine());
        }
        for (Thread t : arrayOfThread) {
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception" + e);
    }
}

public void run() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + x);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished");
}
```

В вашем коде отсутствует вызов метода .start() без которого собственно ничего не порождается.B я не наблюдаю переопределенный метод run ...

я рекомендую к прочтению офф документацию Oracle [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: Да все работает...я думаю Вы не вызвали данный метод из метода main( что то вроде этого) **public static void main(String[] args) {
  new TestClass().threadEngine();
 }**